# Considering the licence, can I use ADB for other purposes than creating an Android application?

Tags: software, licensing, google

When I try to download Android SDK Platform-Tools (with ADB) from the official site (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) it is required to accept the license that states (among others):

> 3.1 Subject to the terms of the License Agreement, Google grants you a limited, worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable, non-exclusive, and non-sublicensable license to use the SDK solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android.

And to maybe add some context:

> 3.2 You may not use this SDK to develop applications for other platforms (including non-compatible implementations of Android) or to develop another SDK. You are of course free to develop applications for other platforms, including non-compatible implementations of Android, provided that this SDK is not used for that purpose.

The statement *"solely to develop applications for compatible implementations of Android"* makes me wonder if it's acceptable for me to use ADB just to do something on my phone (installing an application, doing a backup or maybe even using Scrcpy) which is not really connected to creation of some new app.

How should I understand this paragraph? Or maybe it's not really about ADB (or other tools), but SDK itself (which I not really or not necessarily use while using ADB)?

I tried finding a way to directly contact Google about it, but they suggested using Stack Overflow (https://developers.google.com/sites/support). I decided to post this question on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248983/considering-the-licence-can-i-use-adb-for-other-purposes-then-creating-an-andro) first, as I think it may be considered off-topic there and later [RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/77524/rockpaperlz-mask-it-or-casket) suggested me to post it here too.

Comment: The version of ADB in the Ubuntu repositories appears to be under an Apache 2.0 Licence, which doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: @DanielHatton, thank You for this information! Could You tell me where have You checked that? Does it mean someone just built it and added to repository, instead of using a version provided by Google?

Comment: Binary package description [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/adb) points to source package [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/android-platform-tools), which in turn points to licence information [here](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/a/android-platform-tools/android-platform-tools_29.0.6-4ubuntu1/copyright).

Comment: It's a little more organised than "someone just built it and added to repository": <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution>

Comment: @DanielHatton, thank You very much! Now I know how can I check that stuff myself. And in this case lines "Files: system/core/*
Copyright: 2005-2014, The Android Open Source Project
License: Apache-2.0"  in the file provided under the last link seems crucial.

About "someone just built it and added to repository" the point is that binaries were, as I assume, not directly taken from Google under their licence (partially quoted above), but built from sources and available under different one (Apache 2 I suppose). Thank You anyway!